# Cannot get Internet Explorer instance through SHDocVw in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, automation, shdocvw

I have WPF C# app with this piece of code:

```
foreach(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ie.Location:" + ie.LocationURL);
}
```

At the time of iteration I do have 2 opened Internet Explorer windows. First of those opened the other with JS.

Scenario behind is that in first instance of IE user selects from products and hit create order button. That button opens second instance of IE where formatted order is ready for printing (automatically Print dialog is opened too).

With code above I can only see the first IE instance not the other one. When I manually open some IE windows before iteration I can also see them in shellWindows.

Any ideas why that secondly opened instance of IE is not present in shellWindows?
Any other way how I connect to that second instance of IE?

Comment: It is unlikely that you are actually running two instances, IE is a single-instance app.  If you start it again then it simply asks the first instance to create another window and quits.  Verify your assumptions with Task Manager, Details tab.

Comment: I already verified my assumption with Spy++. I can clearly see another window handle to that second window. In Spy++ in says that second window does not have any parent, so "nested windows" case is also not the one, or? Just to note, both IE windows are open in moment of traversing through `shellWindows`.